# Why indexation raised a lot but visits didn´t?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index, traffic

My website raised its indexing ten times from a day to the next one literally.

It went from about 500K pages to 5 million but the visits have not been increased: absolutely nothing. They even went a bit down.

I understand that the traffic does not have to raise another 10 times, but at lease a little bit.

Is there any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for indexing to Google by submitting a sitemap file or putting some links from other websites to your own doesn't necessarily correlate with your traffic.

Even if fresh content can influence rankings, it doesn't neccesarily increase your traffic when new pages are indexed (especially if your site and/or your new pages are not well SEO-optimized). A new indexed page can increase the traffic when the site is well known by Google and very SEO-wise efficient.

Good ideas to increase your traffic could be found [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google).

Comment: I am not trying to be mean, however, the OPs site has several problems that will cause Google heartburn. Scraped content, thin content, low quality content, etc. Number of pages and the page creation velocity will only make it worse. This site will likely get pinged and may be on Googles radar screen already.

Comment: You can be fully indexed, but if they don't like it, they won't come... Figure out how to produce compelling content that people wish to view.

Answer (score 0):

Interest in anything waxes and wanes. Every bucket can only be filled so far. Popular television programs gain a first time audience but some of them find they're not interested and don't come back.

All of those apply to you.